# Como setar o time_zone usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma conexão utilizando **PDO** que seta o `SET NAMES UTF8`:

```
$options = [ PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8" ];
```

Mas gostaria de adicionar o `SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo'`.Porém de todas as formas que eu tentei ele me retorno uma Exceção!

Comment: O time zone do php? o time do banco é outra coisa. `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');`

Comment: é a configuração do time_zone via PDO na própria conexão!